# Does AWS S3 Same-Region Replication (SRR) uses public or private internet to transfer data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, data-transfer, aws-security-hub

I'm in need of transferring some highly sensitive data and trying to avoid public internet for egress/ingress traffic.

Trying to find out if AWS uses the private(internal) network to replicate objects or uses the public internet to transfer them, but to no avail.

Comment: Not conclusive, but given that there are explicitly no data transfer charges with SRR, it seems extraordinarily unlikely that they're using Internet bandwidth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn’t find a clear document explaining this but got confirmation from AWS that, SRR uses ***backbone internet (the internal private network)*** for such transfers.